# Using Pattern in java

Tags: java, regex, match

I'm practicing with Pattern class in java, and, for example, given a String:

```
String text = "1234bbbbAAAAb2222 /*1231232132131221*/ [11] }";
```

The output should be:

```
Number: 1234
String: bbbbAAAAb
Number: 2222
Commment: /*1231232132131221*/
Symbol: [
Number: 11
Symbol: ]
Symbol: }
```

How could I do this with Pattern using regex, so everything is printed according to the order in the original text ?

My output is not doing in order:

```
Number: 1234
Number: 2222
Number: 11
String: bbbbAAAAb
Commment: /*1231232132131221*/
Symbol: [
Symbol: ]
Symbol: }
```

Comment: Show your program for us java coders and then it can be taken to next level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
String text = "1234bbbbAAAAb2222 /*1231232132131221*/ [11] }";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)|([a-zA-Z]+)|(/\\*.*?\\*/)|([\\[\\]{}])");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null)
        System.out.println("Number: " + m.group(1) );
    else if (m.group(2) != null)
        System.out.println("String: " + m.group(2) );
    else if (m.group(3) != null)
        System.out.println("Comment: " + m.group(3) );
    else if (m.group(4) != null)
        System.out.println("Symbol: " + m.group(4) );
}
```

result:

```
Number: 1234
String: bbbbAAAAb
Number: 2222
Comment: /*1231232132131221*/
Symbol: [
Number: 11
Symbol: ]
Symbol: }
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please tell me what group() does ? And why does it start from 1 ?

Comment: For example, `m.group(1)` returns matched string with the pattern enclosed in the first parentheses (that is `(\\d+)`).  `m.group(0)` returns whole string matched with `pat`.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is good and all, but sometimes it only goes so far. Though it is possible to do this using regex, I think it would be far easier to manually parse it. Just iterate through the string and split it up into segments. If you need some reference for how to do advanced manual parsing, you can take a look at my VParser library: https://github.com/ViperLordX/VParser/blob/master/src/viperlordx/parser/VParser.java

If you do want to use Regex, however, I suggest you use capture groups to get the order in which it found the patterns.